# Sequelize type changing getter/setter with Typescript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

Sequelize version: v6

I am using Sequelize.define to define models. One of the attribute is stored as long text but with getter and setter it is used as an object in the application layer:

```
interface ModelNameAttributes {
  modelId: string;
  extras: string;
  ...
}

interface ModelNameCreationAttributes extends Optional<ModelNameAttributes, 'modelId'> {}

interface ModelNameInstance
  extends Model<ModelNameAttributes, ModelNameCreationAttributes>,
  ModelNameAttributes {}

type ModelNameStatic = typeof Model
& { associate: (models: any) => void }
& { new(values?: Record<string, unknown>, options?: BuildOptions): ModelNameInstance }

module.exports = (sequelize: Sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const ModelName = <ModelStatic>sequelize.define('ModelName', {
    modelId: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
    },
    extras: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT('long'),
      get: function (): {[key: string]: any} {
        let val = this.getDataValue('extras');
        return val && JSON.parse(val);
      },
      set: function (value: {[key: string]: any}): void {
        this.setDataValue('extras', JSON.stringify(value));
      },
    },
    ...,
  })
  return ModelName;
});
```

When I try to create a record with

```
const payload: ModelNameCreationAttributes = {
  extras: { hello: 'hi' },
  ...
};
ModelName.create(payload, { transaction });
```

I got a red line under the `extras` saying:

```
Type '{ [key: string]: any; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

What should I do? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a definition of `extras` in a model interface because for code that will use it it should look as an object and not as a string:

```js
interface ModelNameAttributes {
  modelId: string;
  extras: Record<string, any>;
  ...
}
```

P.S. You also can use `Record<string, any>` instead of `{[key: string]: any}` in the getter.